# How do I print out this 2D array?

Tags: c, loops, printf

Novice programmer here trying to print out a 2D array of asterisks. The output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
*******
 *******
  *******
   *******
```

That's 7 asterisks with a leading space increment by 1 every row with row 1 starting with 0 leading spaces and row 4 starting with 3 leading spaces.

Only the `<stdio.h>` library can be used and I'd like to keep using nested `for` loops. Here's my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, j;
  char star[1] = {'*'};

  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
          printf("%*c", i, star[0]);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
********
********
 * * * * * * * *
  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
```

I'd also like for this question to be an opportunity for me to learn good general programming practices and habits from this community so if you could critique my implementation, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No need for  `multidimensional-array` tag and no need to array at all.

Comment: Ok, I just removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this does not really have anything to do with multidemensional arrays. Secondly you are using the width format specifier in your `printf` call

```
printf("%*c", i, star[0]);
```

and setting that width to be `i`. Therefore each time you call

```
printf("%*c", i, star[0]);
```

you are specifying the minimum width of the printed output to be `i` characters. As your output is a single `*` character this results in whitespace padding.

Thus in your final iteration of your `i` based loop (i = 3) you are causing the string

```
'  *'
```

to be printed each time, penultimate iteration (i = 2)

```
' *'
```

and so on.

As you don't really need a `char` array of length 1, you could get your desired output with

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  if (i > 0)
  {
    printf("%*c",i,' ');
  }
  for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
  {
    printf("%c", '*');
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hmm... yes, I see. If I remove the width indicator, I now get blocks of 7 asterisks without leading spaces. How do I fix it so that the leading spaces grow with each row before the asterisks are printed?

Answer (score 0):

The program you wrote prints space before every star, and that's space length is tied to the 'i' variable'.

You should make it print (spaces * i) before the loop that prints line of 8 stars even starts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would write it.
    #include

```
int main() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
      for( int p = 0; p < i; p++ ) {
          printf(" ");
      }
      for( int j = 0; j < 8; j++ ) {
          printf("*");
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here it is in Python, if you're interested:

```
    for x in range(4):
        print ((x * " ") + ("*" * 7))
```

Apply this same idea of padding the beginning with spaces based on the iteration, and then adding the asterisks

Comment: This is pretty irrelevant

Comment: Can you explain how? I was offering an abstract idea of how to do it in another programming language

Comment: Because the OP specifically asked for a solution in C